# I am trying to resize bundle of images using python. But it resize only 5 images not all

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, resize-image

I am trying to resize bundle of images using python.My folder contain 100 plus Images But it resize only 5 images not all.
Here is my code

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import glob

pathIn = 'C:/Users/Farooq/Desktop/pics'
pathOut = 'C:/Users/Farooq/Desktop/pics/300'
name = 'Image'
newsize = (300,300)
int_desiredLength = 3


if not os.path.exists(pathOut):
    os.makedirs(pathOut)

for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob(pathIn + '/*')):

    fname = name + '_{str_0:0>{str_1}}.jpg'.format(str_0=i+1, str_1=int_desiredLength)
    im = Image.open(file)
    im.thumbnail((newsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    apparent_size = im.size
    apparent_h, apparent_w = im.size
    desired_h, desired_w = newsize
    delt_h, delt_w = abs(apparent_h - desired_h), abs(apparent_w - desired_w)

    padding = (delt_h // 2, delt_w // 2, delt_h - (delt_h // 2), delt_w - (delt_w // 2))
    im = ImageOps.expand(im, padding)
    desired_size = im.size
    print('{0}: {1}====>{2}'.format(fname, apparent_size, desired_size))
    im.save(os.path.join(pathOut, fname))
```

Comment: Your glob should always include the `300` folder you are creating.

Comment: Are you possibly encountering any errors? Because your `glob` pattern is going to also capture the `300` name of your output subdirectory, which probably won't be openable by PIL. Try changing your pattern to `glob.glob(os.path.join(pathIn, '*.jpg'))`

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Any error?